# 稽查 vs. 勘查 meaning, context, and usage

Tags: meaning

稽查 and 勘查 both means to investigate. So what is the difference? How would I distinguish between them and choose which one to utilize if I'm writing something? And the more mainstream term is 調查, so is 稽查 and 勘查 more advanced and fancy wording? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

稽查 - inspection/inspect/check (usually looking for inconsistency, violations, and tax evasion)

1. Government agencies, such as Customs, inspect and verify the accuracy of goods, their quantity, and market value against the owner's filing.
2. A Company conducts an internal inspection of booking and working procedures per the company's rules.

勘查/勘察 - reconnaissance and survey (check field conditions, usually for feasibility of construction.)

調查 - investigate; inquire into (Investigate the background of a person, an event, or a suspect crime.)

Answer (score 1):

稽查 means "to inspect/check/audit". It's close to 检查, but not 调查.
Example usage: 稽查毒品，税务稽查

勘查 means "to survey (natural resources)". Meaning-wise it could be replaced by 调查 but if you work in the mining industry everyone uses 勘查.
Example usage: 矿产资源勘查